# use subquery to show JOB_TITLE

Tags: mysql, sql

i tried to use subquery  to show JOB_TITLE in the result this code work , but i can't add JOB_TITLE 'Jr. Designer' in the result

```
select EMP_ID,F_NAME,L_NAME
from employees
where job_id in (select job_ident from jobs where JOB_TITLE= 'Jr. Designer');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead ofr an IN clause use JOIN

```
select EMP_ID,F_NAME,L_NAME,JOB_TITLE
from employees e INNER JOIN jobs j ON j.job_ident = e.job_id
where JOB_TITLE= 'Jr. Designer';
```

Answer (score 0):

First run this by itself

```
select job_ident from jobs where JOB_TITLE= 'Jr. Designer'
```

do you get any rows back?  if not, then the text does not match and you should fix that.

JOB_ID on the employees table seems like a bad normalization.  I'm supposing that is where it is located or you would get some error that you would post here.  I would suggest normalizing that correctly in either case.

Comment: yes it's work to show  result but just from employees table i need to add job title column to result

Comment: The JOIN is the right way to do this.